# Wordpress loop only displaying one post

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I don't know enough PHP perhaps to recognize immediately why the loop in my wordpress theme is only displaying one post and so I humbly ask for assisstance.

```
<div class="container"> 
    <div class="row">
    <div id="primary" class="content-area col-sm-8">
        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>





<?php 


                get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

            ?> 


            <?php endwhile; ?>

            <?php web2feel_content_nav( 'nav-below' ); ?>

        <?php else : ?>

            <?php get_template_part( 'no-results', 'index' ); ?>

        <?php endif; ?>   

        </main><!-- #main -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->


    </div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I believe that it then references the content.php file which is as follows

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
                <header class="entry-header">
                    <?php if ( 'post' == get_post_type() ) : ?>
                    <div class="entry-meta">
                        <?php web2feel_posted_on(); ?>
                    </div><!-- .entry-meta -->
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <h1 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
                </header><!-- .entry-header -->


                <?php
                    $thumb = get_post_thumbnail_id();
                    $img_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumb,'full' ); //get full URL to image (use "large" or "medium" if the images too big)
                    $image = aq_resize( $img_url, 780, 400, true ); //resize & crop the image
                ?>

                <?php if($image) : ?>
                <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $image ?>"/>
                <?php endif; ?>             


                <div class="entry-summary">
                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                </div><!-- .entry-summary -->

                <footer class="entry-meta">
                    <?php if ( 'post' == get_post_type() ) : // Hide category and tag text for pages on Search ?>
                        <?php
                            /* translators: used between list items, there is a space after the comma */
                            $categories_list = get_the_category_list( __( ', ', 'web2feel' ) );
                            if ( $categories_list && web2feel_categorized_blog() ) :
                        ?>
                        <span class="cat-links">
                            <?php printf( __( 'Posted in %1$s', 'web2feel' ), $categories_list ); ?>
                        </span>
                        <?php endif; // End if categories ?>

                        <?php
                            /* translators: used between list items, there is a space after the comma */
                            $tags_list = get_the_tag_list( '', __( ', ', 'web2feel' ) );
                            if ( $tags_list ) :
                        ?>
                        <span class="tags-links">
                            <?php printf( __( 'Tagged %1$s', 'web2feel' ), $tags_list ); ?>
                        </span>
                        <?php endif; // End if $tags_list ?>
                    <?php endif; // End if 'post' == get_post_type() ?>

                    <?php if ( ! post_password_required() && ( comments_open() || '0' != get_comments_number() ) ) : ?>
                    <span class="comments-link"><?php comments_popup_link( __( 'Leave a comment', 'web2feel' ), __( '1 Comment', 'web2feel' ), __( '% Comments', 'web2feel' ) ); ?></span>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                    <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'web2feel' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?>
                </footer><!-- .entry-meta -->
            </article><!-- #post-## -->
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to check your settings from wordpress admin.

go to `admin->Settings->Reading` and check that `Blog pages show at most` should not be 1. if it's one than increase it.

Comment: Hi, I did check this but this isn't the case. I know that it is something wrong with the index.php file's functionality because when I change the static home page to be just a blog page it ends up with the same results.